# How to perform click for a drop down in angular2

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I have the following drop down and I am unable to perform click on select of one of the option.

```
 <select >
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab" (click)="get()">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>

get() {
   alert('hi');
}
```

Comment: instread of `(click)` you should use `ng-click=`

Comment: sorry i am using angular 2

Comment: try this `<select [(ngModel)] = "model" (click)="get()">...`

Comment: @MMR you should use ngModelChange

Answer (score 1):

You can use **(change)** event .

```
<select (change)="onchange(event)">
 <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
 <option value="saab">Saab</option>
 <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
 <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>

onchange(event) {
 if(event.target.value=="saab")
  {
    //perform your action
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should have the **`change`** for the **`select`** , not for the option,

```
   <select  [(ngModel)] = "selected"  (change)="onchange(event)">
      <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
      <option value="saab" >Saab</option>
      <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
      <option value="audi">Audi</option>
    </select>
```

**[`DEMO`](https://plnkr.co/edit/v3whQ6?p=preview)**